# output as UTF-8 encoding in java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

I am having problem with the output file from a program using eclipse .i set my eclipse to UTF-8 and with

```
 System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

i get UTF-8.i ran my prog via eclipse run-option and the output (a text file) is encoded in UTF-8.but when i compressed the source code into a jar file,the output file shows error in some of the alphabet like Ã.what is with this diff when ruuning the prog in eclipse and frm jar file?and do i have to specify the output to be encoded in utf-8 in my source code?pls help.

help from @dacwe indeed produced the desired output.but may i know how can i run my executable .jar file outside command line?how can the -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

@dacwe :i tried changing my source code into

```
 BufferedWriter bout  = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter(
                new java.io.FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```

but the output still is not encoded correctly.anything i miss here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the default Java character encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding)

Comment: Don't do that! Stop setting environment variables or system properties to set the encoding to use. All relevant classes in Java have constructors that take the encoding. Specify the correct encoding there and you will never have to rely on external configuration again.

Comment: @dacwe i did not mention any use of System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8") in my source code.so running my code via eclipse run always produce the desired result(utf-8 encoded file) but not in .jar file.

Comment: @reukEN11: The answer in that question may apply anyway? Start your jar with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8`.

Answer (score 16):

After some major discussion in @Dave G's answer!

Using `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your-jar-file.jar` works.

Updating your code as @Dave G suggested (and your edit) should work.

- Have you really repackaged your jar?
- Do you call `close()` on `bout`? (e.g. maybe your file isn't updated)

---

Here is a full example that might get you going:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("hello.txt"), "UTF-8");
    out.print("written in utf-8");
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: i repackaged the.jar file after each changes in my source code to determine the output and also bout.close() was already added.none that work except when using console.and whats the problem with my BufferedWriter?

Comment: @reukEN11: No problem with your `BufferedWriter`. I just wanted to write a concise example. If you read files you need to use the correct encoding there aswell.

Comment: @dacwei see.so i did changed the mybufferedwriter to specifically include the char set.repackaged and run,but the prob still exists.will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

When you run from a JAR file are you setting the file.encoding property by -Dfile.encoding?  If not, you can <strike>either</strike>

a) open the stream explicitly with that encoding. for this you will have to create an OutputStream and then wrap that in an OutputStreamWriter explicitly indicating the character encoding.

<strike>or</strike>

b) set the property as the first thing in your main method using System.setProperty("file.endcoding");

**note** @dacwe pointed out something I forgot ... corrected my answer.

Comment: b) is not correct. You must set the `file.encoding` before the JVM starts up (it is cached by for example `String` and `OutputStreamWriter`..).

Comment: @dacwe i use export as .jar file from eclipse to compress my source code.how exactly can i set up this property?i look into eclipse and it has .ini file,with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 at the last line(manually from tutorial to set ide in utf).

Comment: @reukEN11: *If you do not use your source code in the program it has nothing to to with the source.* Start your application from a shell with: `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar your-jar-file.jar`.

Comment: @dacwe desired result indeed.can this -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 be embedded into jar file when running executable jar ie prefer running outside command line.and i tried using

Comment: @reukEN11: Use the answer that Dave G provided. When constructing your `OutputStreamWriter` you provide the encoding (second argument).