# embedding preferred encoding instruction into a java program

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, executable-jar, opencsv

my problem continues from here [utf-8 as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733029/output-as-utf-8-encoding-in-java).Currently i am using:

```
PrintWriter bout = new java.io.PrintWriter(filename,"UTF-8");
```

and it still is not working .as @dacwe suggested,i used command line with

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to execute my .jar file and it worked,where the desired utf-8 file output was created(no alphabets prob).So i am thinking this workaround like how eclipse.exe works with .ini file in eclipse directory.can i wrap my java prog into exe and have the program to include the .ini file?or can someone suggest any workable idea?my program read csv file (from opencsv) and output as a text in UTF-8.

Comment: Setting encoding in PrintWriter is perfectly enough. Are you reading the file from java or using some text file editor?

Comment: @Max in a class of my prog,this was declared : CSVReader reader1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader(inputFilePath),';').so file is read by java-by opencsv of course.

Comment: @Max : yes.it is OpenCsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this question: [Parse CSV file containing a Unicode character using OpenCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695699/parse-csv-files-that-contain-unicode-character-using-opencsv)

You should use your CSVReader like this:

```
CSVReader reader=new CSVReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("d:\\a.csv"), "UTF-8"), 
    ',', '\'', 1);
```

And you do not need to set any environment properties like `file.encoding` or anything else.

Comment: i am confused here.as the documentation stated,there is no such constructor.

Comment: The constructor is described here: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVReader.html . It is just that instead of a `FileReader` (which does not support encoding) a `InputStreamReader` is created which does support encoding. InputStreamReader reads from any streams, so you need to give it a stream to read from (in constructor). In this case it uses `FileInputStream` which opens the file and makes it a stream. So the full flow becomes File -> FileInputStream -> InputStreamReader -> CSVReader

Comment: thx for the solution and explanation.it solved my prob with the encoding.

Comment: Using this method will hard code the encoding used by the application. It might be more desirable to pass the encoding as a parameter to the application. Using UTF-8 as the default if no encoding specified.

Comment: Maybe. Anyway I would rather recommend to pass it as some configuration file rather than a JVM option.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell script or batch file to pass the JVM parameters.

Example shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar yourJar.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 "$@"
```

For windows batch files have a look at http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm